# Implementing the takePicture method with received Bluetooth data

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-camera

I am trying to capture a picture when certain data has been read from a Bluetooth socket.

I am quite new to Android and I can't figure out how to implement the `takePicture()` method without a click listener. Currently I have a button which when clicked will capture the image, like this:

```
 OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
     }
};
```

I want to completely remove this so I can take the picture remotely.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this only when you connect your app to the remote bluetooth device, and read the socket data. Simply call your method  mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture) from the place where you are reading the server socket data.
Refer to this link to understand the basic read, write in classic bluetooth(i.e. below 4.0)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java

If your bluetooth remote device is BLE i.e. Bluetooth 4.0, then connection procedure will be different

Comment: I am actually doing some signal analysis on a PC and I plan to connect to the Android as a client and send a key if a certain signal is generated, do you think this will still work?